# How accurate is Wavelet packet decomposition for emg signals with frequencies from 10 to 40 Hz?

Tags: discrete-signals, wavelet, time-frequency, emg, pattern

I have an electromyographic signal sampled at a frequency between 10 and 40 Hz in a time window of 300ms. Is wavelet packet decomposition adequate in order to perform features extraction for subsequent pattern recognition?

Comment: Which wavelets, what features?

Comment: i don't know what wavelet, the question is about the usage of the method in general. the features are the wavelet packets. themself, furtherly processed through feature reduction/projection and then classification.